# WPF Custom Font Rendering

Tags: wpf, xaml, fonts

I have been given a custom font to use in our corporate application.  The font itself looks fine in Word, but is rendered "elevated" by WPF.  Consider the screen prints below:

When the Calibre font is rendered in WPF (I manually drew the red line):
[image: When the Calibre font is rendered in WPF]

When the Calibre font is rendered in Word:
[image: When the Calibre font is rendered in Word]
XAML:

```html
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,10,0,100">
  <TextBlock Text="Arial" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="48" Padding="5,0" Margin="0" Background="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  <TextBlock Text="Arial Bold" FontFamily="Arial Bold" FontSize="48" Padding="5,0" Margin="0" Background="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
  <TextBlock Text="Calibre Regular" FontFamily="Calibre Regular" FontSize="48" Padding="5,0" Margin="0" Background="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
  <TextBlock Text="Calibre Bold" FontFamily="Calibre Bold" FontSize="48" Padding="5,0" Margin="0" Background="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
  <TextBlock Text="Calibri Regular" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="48" Padding="5,0" Margin="0" Background="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
  <TextBlock Text="Calibri Bold" FontFamily="Calibri Bold" FontSize="48" Padding="5,0" Margin="0" Background="AntiqueWhite" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
</StackPanel>
```

Any idea?  I am truly stumped on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I stumbled across a fix.  I opened the font in a free font editor called Type Light to verify everything looked correct in the font.  I saved the font as a new file and tried that file.  It solved the issue.  Clearly something was wrong with the OTF file.

http://www.cr8software.net/typelight.html